# Hindu scripture for gardening

Tags: plants

Just like Ayurveda is the science of medicine in Sanaatan Dharm (Hinduism), what is the book for gardening skills/practices according to Sanaatan Dharm?

I want to know of the book/scripture which details on the knowledge of growing plants, do’s and don’t’s related to gardening, just like Ayurveda talks about medicine and the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vṛkṣāyurveda (वृक्षायुर्वेद) seems a proper term for gardening and other allied subjects on plants & trees.

- There's a chapter in the Varāhamihira's composition - Bṛhatsaṃhitā

> [Chapter 55](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihat-samhita/d/doc229299.html) - On Gardening (vṛkṣāyurveda)

---

- There is brief reference in the  Agni Purāṇa too

> [Chapter 282](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083511.html) - Description of Horticulture (vṛkṣāyurveda)
>
> and
>
> [Chapter 70](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083250.html) - Mode of planting trees (vṛkṣa-pratiṣṭhā)

---

As per this research paper<sup>1</sup> on [Vṛkṣāyurveda](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4140025/)

> Treatises such as [Kṛṣi-Parāśara](https://ia800200.us.archive.org/34/items/Bibliotheca_Indica_Series/KrishiParasara-GirijaPrasannaMajumdarScBanerji1960bis.pdf), [Kaśyapīyakṛṣisūkti](https://archive.org/details/KashyapiyaKrishiPaddhati), Mānasollāsa ([1](https://ia801602.us.archive.org/27/items/Mus-SourceTexts/TxtSkt-mAnasOllAsa-Somesvara-vol1-0024.pdf) & [2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.280843/mode/2up)), Vṛkṣāyurveda and Lokopakāra were dedicated to the art of growing plants for use and pleasure.

---

Footnote 1: Suresh, G., Haridasan, K. and Krishnamurthy, K., 2013. Relevance of Vṛkṣāyurveda and other traditional methods for organic production of nursery seedlings of useful plants. Ancient Science of Life, 33(1), p.60.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this great video by **Project Shivoham** on वृक्षायुर्वेद (vrikshayurved) which gives an introduction to what is contained in this branch of Indian Science:

https://youtu.be/gyLCZECB8nI